# Differences between query routes in nextjs using next-routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, server-side-rendering, next.js

I'm working on a project with next.js and Reactjs that uses a lot of different languages. So I need to change the language url. Example:

> www.example.com/es/entradas
>
> www.example.com/en/tickets
>
> www.example.com/de/eintrittskarten

To make routes I saw that there is a module that helps me: next-routes

> https://github.com/fridays/next-routes

There are a lot of url and I'm working with a CMS, so my clients will be able to add more, so routes can't be harcoded. I thought to pass the url with queries, like this:

```
const routes = require('next-routes');

module.exports = routes()
  .add('index', '/:lang?')
  .add('tickets', '/:lang?/:ticket')
  .add('hotel', '/:lang?/:hotel');
```

My surprise (as you might see), it doesn't work because routes doesn't see the difference between these two last routes. If I write:

> www.example.com/en/tickets

It will go correctly to my page "tickets" but if I write

> www.example.com/en/hotel

It will go again to my page "tickets" and not to "hotel"

Do you know any way about how could I make this?

---

In my project I have these files related about routes:

server.js

```
const next = require('next');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const routes = require('./routes');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dir: './src/shared', dev });
const handle = routes.getRequestHandler(app);

app.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    createServer(handle)
  .listen(3001, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:3001");
  });
});
```

routes.js

```
const routes = require('next-routes');


module.exports = routes()
  .add('index', '/:lang?')
  .add('tickets', '/:lang?/:ticket')
  .add('hotel', '/:lang?/:hotel');
```

Answer (score 0):

The request for `/en/hotel` is going to the "ticket" route because it is actually matching it.

This is because of the `:` in front of the word "ticket" in the route. A `:` will turn a section of a route into a parameter with that name.

So instead what you probably want is:

```
module.exports = routes()
  .add('index', '/:lang?')
  .add('tickets', '/:lang?/ticket')
  .add('hotel', '/:lang?/hotel');
```